# What is the difference between protected internal static and internal static in C#?

Tags: c#, static, protected, access-modifiers

In my C# assembly "Abc", I have the following class and static method:

```
internal class Xyz
{
    protected internal static void MakeAwesome()
    {
        ...       
    }
}
```

I noticed I can access this static method from anywhere in my assembly code.
However, removing the "protected" from it seems to yield the same results:

```
internal class Xyz
{
    internal static void MakeAwesome()
    {
        ...       
    }
}
```

Is the "protected" here making no difference because it's a static method? Or is it restricting something I overlooked?

Comment: static has nothing to do with access modifiers. The duplicate answers this.

Comment: Sigh, yeah. I mixed up the meaning of protected internal once again.

Comment: Not an exactly duplicate because of the static keyword

Comment: @kenny and the internal keyword the class is decorated with. but still the same trap i fell into

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`protected` means that it can also be accessed from derived classes.

In your case, since the class itself is internal, you cannot have derived classes outside the project, so it doesn't add anything to `internal`.